# MobileFirst Platform - firewall rules to send push notifications

Tags: push-notification, firewall, ibm-mobilefirst

According to the documentation, these are the ports to be opened on a firewall to send notifications from a server, but it is unclear whether to allow the  inbound and outbound connections in the firewall or only outbound connections:

> For push notification to be sent, the following servers must be accessible from a MobileFirst Server instance:
>
> **iOS**
>
> Sandbox servers:
>   gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
>   feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196
>   Production servers:
>   gateway.push.apple.com:2195
>   Feedback.push.apple.com:2196
>   1-courier.push.apple.com 5223
>
> **Android**
>   The ports to open are: 443, 5228, 5229, and 5230. GCM typically uses only 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230.
>   GCM does not provide specific IP addresses, so you must allow your firewall to accept outgoing connections to all IP addresses that are contained in the IP blocks listed in Google ASN of 15169.
>
> **Windows Phone 8**
>   No specific port needs to be open in your server configuration.
>   MPNS uses regular http or https requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both incoming and outgoing...

As an example, which will apply to all vendors, see Apple's support document: https://support.apple.com/en-ap/HT203609

If you have iOS devices inside your network, then for the devices to receive the notification you must have the following available for incoming connections:

> For APNs traffic to get past your firewall, you'll need to open these
> ports:
>
> - TCP port 5223 (used by devices to communicate to the APNs
>   servers)
> - TCP port 2195 (used to send notifications to the APNs)
> - TCP port 2196 (used by the APNs feedback service)
> - TCP Port 443 (used as a fallback on Wi-fi only, when devices are unable to communicate to APNs on port 5223)
>
> The APNs servers use load balancing. Your devices will
> not always connect to the same public IP address for notifications.
> The entire 17.0.0.0/8 address block is assigned to Apple, so it's best
> to allow this range in your firewall settings.

And since apple's servers have a specific range and ports, you need them open for outgoing connections as well...

Comment: I understand that you need to open inbound connections only for IOS and Windows Phone, because android notifies that outgoing connections are only required: "... so you must allow your firewall to accept outgoing connections to all IP addresses that are contained in the IP blocks listed in Google ASN of 15169."

Comment: MobileFirst does not require anything for push to work; follow the instructions by the vendors.

Comment: I intend to put a firewall in front of MobileFirst server, this question comes from the servers notification (APNS, GCM, MPNS) may submit responses to MobileFirst server, if, for example, the target app is uninstalled on the target device.

Comment: The mentioned ports need to be open for outgoing and incoming connections.

Comment: why incoming as well for sending push?

Comment: It says so. Feedback service.